# Django ORM Equivalent for MySql multiple-column IN clause

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

Is there a way to make the following query using Django ORM?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (x, y) IN ((1, 'a'), (2, 'b'))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about Q objects?

```
query = reduce(operator.or_, [Q(x=d[0], y=d[1]) for d in [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]]

Table1.objects.filter(query)
```